# How to Set Background Image with using introduction_screen package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How to Set Background Image with introduction_screen Package.

Package Link: https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen

Thank you for giving me your important time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
  PageViewModel(
      title: "Title of first page",
      bodyWidget:    Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("your source"))),),
```

you also can use NetworkImage for get on link instead of AssetImage